# How can I 'disable' left_C-x and enable only 'right_C'-x

Tags: key-bindings

I'm a emacs user, and my left pinkie start to feel it a bit (overuse of C-x day long) .... so I thought that before crying over some emacs induced RSI, I should unset some bindings so my bad habits would not have any chance at being effective.

I'm wondering: is it possible to enable the `C-x` binding only with the right `ctrl` key, and not the left, within emacs ? I could disactivate the key altogether (or even remove it physically from the keyboard while I'm at it) but it seems a bit overkill, and a softer solution would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you are looking for something like [that solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126795/66437). You can disable Control_L on system level.

Comment: Yes, it can make the job. A more local solution (emacs specific) would be even better to prevent messing with my other bindings where I enjoy using the left control. But I also might use the occasion to switch to space maps or some other binding system before my small finger starts to become really painful.

Comment: As described in the [referred solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126795/66437), only one control modifier is sent to the application (e.g., Emacs). So you are out of local options without changes of the X-keys.